# Markdown to HTML from Ant or Commandline

Tags: java, html, ant, continuous-integration, markdown

I have a build server (running windows) and would like to convert markdown (including tables) to HTML.
I don't want to write software for this but rather use something existing from the Java World.

The whole thing should work from the command line:

Example:

```
java -jar some.jar -Dinput someMarkdownfile.md -Doutput someOutputfile.html
```

Is there an elegant way to do something like this?

**Update**: Java is not a hard "must-be" in my case. I thought that Java is a good option so it would be platform independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a java solution you could use [markdownj](https://code.google.com/p/markdownj/)

The following example uses [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to retrieve the jar from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.markdownj%7Cmarkdownj%7C0.3.0-1.0.2b4%7Cjar)

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="markdownj" default="build">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path">
            <dependency org="org.markdownj" name="markdownj" rev="0.3.0-1.0.2b4" conf="default"/>
        </ivy:cachepath>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="resolve">
        <java classname="com.petebevin.markdown.MarkdownProcessor" classpathref="build.path" input="test.markdown" output="test.html">
        </java>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a command line tool that does just what I want to do:

[Multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) can handle tables and converts `HTML` output like so:

```
mulimarkdown.exe -o someOutputfile.html someMarkdownfile.md
```

What is a bit tedious is that I don't have an option to provide a CSS but I can do that manually by stitching together a header the generated content and a footer.